# Retrieving button block using "Retrieving block children" endpoint

Tags: notion-api, notion

If I use the **"Retrieve block children"** endpoint to get all the blocks info by giving page_id as input, the type of the "Button" block is showing unsupported. Want some information on this.

Tried getting the info about the "Button" block. Getting "type": "unsupported".
Was expecting "type": "button"

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Notion API Block Reference](https://developers.notion.com/reference/block):

> **The API does not support all block types.**
>
> Only the block type objects listed in the reference below are supported. Any unsupported block types appear in the structure, but contain a `type` set to `"unsupported"`.

As a workaround, to use buttons with the API you currently have to manually create a `synced_block` containing the button using the web interface, get the UUID for that synced block, then create a new `synced_block` and set the `synced_from` property to that UUID:

```
{
    "type": "synced_block",
    "synced_block": {
        "synced_from": {
            "block_id": "original_synced_block_id"
        }
    }
}
```

All person/page relations like `Person who clicked button` and `This Page` work as expected.